# Creating several variables/constraints in one shot in SCIP

Tags: linear-programming, scip

I have a C++ application that can use indistinctly (vía polymorphism and virtual methods) `CPLEX`, `GUROBI` or `COIN` to solve an LP, and now I'm adding support for `SCIP`.

In the first three solvers I can add several constraints/variables at once, using the calls:

- Constraints

```
CPLEX  = CPXXaddrows
GUROBI = GRBXaddconstrs
COIN   = OsiSolverInterface::addRows
```

- Variables

```
CPLEX  = CPXXaddcols
GUROBI = GRBXaddvars
COIN   = OsiSolverInterface::addCols
```

But for `SCIP`, I've only figured out how to do it one by one:

- Constraints

```
SCIPcreateConsBasicLinear -> SCIPaddCoefLinear-> SCIPaddCons -> SCIPreleaseCons
```

- Variables

```
SCIPcreateVarBasic -> SCIPaddVar -> SCIPreleaseVar
```

My question is: Is there a way in `SCIP` to create several variables/constraints in one instruction? I ask because, at least for the other solvers, doing it that way is a lot faster than doing it one by one.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SCIP you have to create variables and constraints one by one.